# SQL db relationship between two models

Tags: flask, relationship

I'm currently making a website and having some troubles with showing user the {{ patient.name }} with out them writing it. The name can be just filter by the patient.id, if patient.id and detail.id has the same id, for example 1, then they are sharing the same name and information.
Although I'm just getting errors in

routes.py

```
@app.route("/add-patient-detail/<int:patient_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
@login_required  
def add_patient_detail(patient_id): 
    form = DetailForm()   
    if form.validate_on_submit():  
        detail = Detail(detail=patient.id, Symptom=form.Symptom.data,  Initial_diagnosis=form.Initial_diagnosis.data,
        Preliminary_treatment_plan=form.Preliminary_treatment_plan.data, Check_result=form.Check_result.data, 
        Patient_reason=form.Patient_reason.data, Formula=form.Formula.data) # detail=patient.id is the part with error
        db.session.add(detail) 
        db.session.commit() 
        flash('此患者已被加入进数据库当中', 'success') 
        return redirect(url_for('home'))     
    return render_template('add-patient-detail.html', title='Add Patient Detail', form=form)
```

models.py

```
class Patient(db.Model, UserMixin): 
    __bind_key__ = 'patient'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    name = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    number = db.Column(db.String(11), unique=False, nullable=False) 
    gender = db.Column(db.String(2), nullable=False) 
    birth = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False) 
    IDcard = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=False) 
    create = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now)   
    details = db.relationship('Detail', backref='detail', lazy=True)  

class Detail(db.Model, UserMixin): 
    __bind_key__ = 'detail'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
    Symptom = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    Initial_diagnosis = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False) 
    Preliminary_treatment_plan = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False) 
    Check_result = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False) 
    Patient_reason = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=False, nullable=False) 
    Formula = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=False, nullable=False)
    Doctor_name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False) 
    Date_of_diagnosis = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now)  
    patient_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('patient.id'), nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things i'm noticing:  
 1.) You are passing `patient_detail` to your endpoint, `patient.id` is not defined anywhere so you won't be able to use that. 
2.) There is no column called `detail` on your `Detail` model. From looking at your model, the join would be on the `patient_id` column.

Try this:

```
@app.route("/add-patient-detail/<int:patient_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
@login_required  
def add_patient_detail(patient_id): #NOTE that you're passing patient_id not patient.id
    form = DetailForm()   
    if form.validate_on_submit():  
        detail = Detail(patient_id=patient_id, Symptom=form.Symptom.data,  Initial_diagnosis=form.Initial_diagnosis.data,
        Preliminary_treatment_plan=form.Preliminary_treatment_plan.data, Check_result=form.Check_result.data, 
        Patient_reason=form.Patient_reason.data, Formula=form.Formula.data) # detail=patient.id is now patient_id=patient_id 
        db.session.add(detail) 
        db.session.commit() 
        flash('此患者已被加入进数据库当中', 'success') 
        return redirect(url_for('home'))     
    return render_template('add-patient-detail.html', title='Add Patient Detail', form=form)
```

Note where I changed what I mentioned in 1) and 2).

Comment: ahhh, How can I make these stupid mistakes

Comment: It happens to everyone!!! Hope you enjoy your time with Flask.